# Unexpected data found date format?

Tags: php, invalidargumentexception

There is`timestamp` field (not null) in UTC in database with value: `2019-08-09 20:06:08`.

I tried to convert this time to local time using function:

```
private function toLocalTime($dateInUTC) {
        $time = strtotime($dateInUTC.' UTC');
        return date("d/m/Y H:i", $time);
}
```

**Converting is:**

```
$response = []; // Data is present here
foreach($response as $v) {
   $v->created_at = $this->toLocalTime($v->created_at);
}
```

On line where I call `$this->toLocalTime()` I get exception:

[image]

**I have tried this code:**

```
$timestamp = '2019-08-09 10:41:00';
$date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp, 'UTC');
$date->setTimezone('your/timezone'); // 
$new_date = $date->format('your new format'); // Y-m-d H:i:s
```

[image]

Maybe my `$timestamp` is empty somewhere?

Comment: your looping an empty array

Comment: So you are setting `$response` to an empty array and then looping over it?

Comment: What function is throwing the _Unexpected data found_ error? It looks like you've got a trace right there.

Comment: the response `array` is empty. BTW, using `gmdate("d/m/Y H:i", strtotime($v->created_at))` would give you the `UTC` time directly, see [gmdate](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.gmdate.php) on `php.net` docs.

Comment: Array is filled, I just shorted it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see you have Carbon in your project:

```
$timestamp = '2019-08-09 10:41:00';
$date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp, 'UTC');

$date->setTimezone('America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires'); // or your timezone
$new_date = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // or your new format
```

in your example:

```
private function toLocalTime($dateInUTC) 
{
    // parse your date with carbon and set that as UTC
    $date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $dateInUTC, 'UTC');
    // set your timezone to get a local time.
    $date->setTimezone('America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires'); // or your timezone
    return = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // or your new format
}
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

If you don't have Carbon installed as your example using native php:

```
private function toLocalTime($dateInUTC) 
{

    $utc_date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $dateInUTC), new DateTimeZone('UTC'));

    $utc_date->setTimeZone(new \DateTimeZone('America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires'); // or your timezone

    return $utc_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // or your new format
}
```

Comment: Have you updated your timezone? https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php  . For example: 'America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires'

Comment: I have Carbon installed

Comment: Perhaps problem in Laravel model sugar free created_at field?

Comment: Yes, but you need to get your time zone to define it. where are you?

Comment: Lets assume that I have Carbon date not string date, how to set timezone for that ?

Comment: You have in your database datetime in UTC right? See the second part in my example!

Comment: Something is wrong with line: `DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $dateInUTC), new DateTimeZone('UTC'));`

Comment: Class 'App\Exports\DateTime' not found"

Comment: Call to a member function setTimeZone() on bool

Comment: I have updated that. but you have Carbon already installed, Use it! Use my second exmaple, the Carbon one.

Comment: private function toLocalTime($dateInUTC) 
{
    // parse your date with carbon and set that as UTC
    $date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $dateInUTC, 'UTC');
    // set your timezone to get a local time.
    $date->setTimezone('America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires'); // or your timezone
    return = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // or your new format
}

Comment: I used this, it give error: `exception: "InvalidArgumentException"
file: "C:\Dev\ch-guestsreg-backend\vendor\nesbot\carbon\src\Carbon\Carbon.php"
line: 917
message: "Data missing"`

Comment: mmm in that case your datetime data is not good. make sure your datetime is correct with format "Y-m-d H:i:s"